# Difference between the strong-AI (AGI) and cognitive science

Tags: cognitive-psychology, artificial-intelligence

I like to know the differences in the objectives of those fields.

Comment: This is way too broad, you could write books on it.

Comment: Can i know just the objectives of the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An AGI is a man-made machine that can learn, adapt, think, plan, predict, etc.

Cognitive science is the study of how our "biological machines" do those same processes.

Comment: Thank you. What is the meaning of achieve AGI through AI (in contrast with AGI through Cognitive Science)? If it dont have simple answer, can you point me to a link? I couldn't find anything through Google.

Comment: @Karthiprime AGI is AI, just more advanced. So no matter what, AGI will be some form of artificial intelligence. Studying Cognitive science just gives us some ideas of how AGI might look when we implement it. It's like studying bird wings to learn how to build a plane. There are some characteristics of physics to learn from bird wings, and plane wings will look similar to bird wings. "Artifical Flyers" will be similar to "Biological Flyers", even though it will be more efficient to do some things different (IE fixed wings).